# How would I read a file out to the user (in PHP) without exhausting memory?

Tags: php, memory-management, file-io, buffer

I am restricting files from being downloaded without authorization, so they can only be downloaded by url such as `mysite.com/getfile.php?file=32tf2376r327yf`. I've read that using `readfile()` can work, but will fill the buffer with the entire file prior to sending it. If 100 users all request it at the same time, that will exhaust memory.

Instead, I want to write out chunks/lines of the file as they're recieved and then fulsh and clear the buffer so that minimal memory is used at any time. How would I do this?

**PSEUDO-CODE**

```
function sendFile($someFile)
{
    //Start the buffer
    ob_start();

    //Send the headers
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.pdf"');
    header('Content-length: ' . (string) (filesize($someFile)));
    ...etc...

    //Get the file (Should I be using "b" mode?)
    $handle = fopen($someFile, "rb");

    if ($handle) {
        //Loop through data, one part at a time
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {

            //Send data
            echo $buffer;

            //Flush the buffer
            ob_flush();

            //Clear buffer
            ob_clean();
        }

        //Error...
        if (!feof($handle)) echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";

        fclose($handle);

        //Make sure everything's sent and clear the buffer
        ob_end_flush();
    }
}
```

What else do I need to do to achieve what I'm trying to do? Is it possible in PHP?

Comment: why you're using buffer at all?

Comment: @YourCommonSense If I simply call `readfile()` that will actually write the whole file to the buffer prior to sending. I don't know of any way other than explicitly using the `ob_` functions to force flushing and clearing of the buffer. By default, I think PHP always puts it in memory first.

Comment: readfile() ___doesn't___ use php memory (unless you buffer it), it's spooled directly to php://output

Comment: food for think: http://www.garfieldtech.com/blog/readfile-memory

Comment: @Dagon Thank you for the link. The problem is my code will have to run in Wordpress which turns on buffering by default. So readfile will not work that way without some extra work to make sure it's off or flushed consistently. That's what I'm asking about.

Comment: @MarkBaker The problem is my code will have to run in Wordpress which turns on buffering by default.

Comment: You're turning on buffering yourself here though, you can't blame wordpress for that

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you for the comment. It appears, what I need is this: `if ( ob_get_level() === 1 ) ob_end_flush();` And then call the headers and `readfile()`. That guarantees the buffer is off. Can you please post that as an answer (since you pointed it out) and I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score -1):

if you *really* care for the memory, and you have a reason to do so, then use nginx as a web-server and php-fpm as PHP API.

with such a setup there will be absolutely no reason to worry about any memory problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot guarantee what web server will be used with this (I'm writing a plugin). I need it to work across different web servers that can run PHP.

Comment: then leave this memory business for someone who would run it.